# QR Code to View Pdf file or any other file In c#

Tags: c#, zxing

i want create a code using which i can convert a pdf to qr Code and scan it to view pdf file

i have used zxing to convert text to qr code
but finding it difficult for the pdf files

Bitmap bitmap = barcodeWriter.Write(textBox1.Text);

Comment: I'm using https://selectpdf.com/community-edition/ this seems to do the job however support sucks. as for the QR code, Google has a nice option for that, for sure you will share data with google as you're the product when you share your data with google but you might like that as a link is good for google to have..

Comment: QR code has a limit on how many bytes you can encode in it (around 3000 for bytes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage). Are you sure you have a file or content which fits in that limit? Which QR code reader do you use which would support what you are trying to do? Why do you not show the PDF directly or provide a download link?